# Does Cartomancer's Hidden Ace allow you to bypass the casting time of a spell with a long casting time?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, spellcasting

The new Cartomancer feat from *The Book of Many Things* has a feature, **Hidden Ace**, that says "when you finish a long rest, you can choose one spell from your class's spell list and imbue that spell into a card." After this you can "you can use a bonus action to flourish the card and cast the spell within."

A 15th-level Wizard, could choose to imbue  **Antipathy/Sympathy** into a card as they finish a long rest. **Antipathy/Sympathy** has a casting time of 1 Hour. When the Wizard uses their bonus action to flourish the card and cast the spell, is it immediately cast without the 1 Hour casting time?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### "The chosen spell must have a casting time of 1 action"

Cartomancer states:

> The chosen spell must have a casting time of 1 action

So you cannot choose a spell with a longer casting time.

Comment: Although, Wish is a spell that takes a bonus action to cast...

Comment: @DanielTose: The version of the rule that I'm seeing says that the spell's level "must be less than or equal to your proficiency bonus." Proficiency bonuses don't go up to +9, so you can't use this trick on ninth level spells at all. That's... probably for the best, but by the time a player has access to *Wish*, "balance" is more a matter of fluff than crunch anyway.

Comment: This wins the price for most concise, complete answer.

Comment: @Kevin So there's no way to get a proficiency bonus of +9?

Comment: @Nzall No, prof bonus caps at 6.

Comment: @Kevin I'm seeing that in the UA version, but not the actual book version. Text i'm seeing: "Hidden Ace. When you finish a long rest, you can choose one spell from your class’s spell list and imbue that spell into a card. The chosen spell must have a casting time of 1 action, and it must be a level for which you have spell slots. The card remains imbued with this spell for 8 hours. While the card is imbued with the spell, you can use a bonus action to flourish the card and cast the spell within. The card then immediately loses its magic."